# HttpHandler Returning Zero Length byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services, httphandler

I have a custom HttpHandler that invokes a webservice to get a file.  In test, I invoke the production webservice and the HttpHandler returns the file correctly.  When I test it in the production environment on the server, it works as well.  However, if I invoke the HttpHandler from a remote client (not on the server) the filename and size are set correctly, but the file bytes that are downloaded are zero.  Any ideas?

Comment: Post the code, and inspect what happens with Wireshark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's the deal.  I created a [multipart range handler](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/http/draft-fielding-http/p5-range.html) (you need to implement the RFC in order to stream content to, say, an iPhone or Adobe Reader).  The spec is suppose to enable handling a file when the client requests a range of bytes instead of the whole array.  The issue with my handler came when the client wanted the whole BLOB:

```
if (context.Request.Headers[HEADER_RANGE] != null)
{
  ...
}
else
{
    context.Response.ContentType = contentItem.MimeType;
    addHeader(context.Response, HEADER_CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + contentItem.Filename + "\"");
    addHeader(context.Response, HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH, contentItem.FileBytes.Length.ToString());
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(contentItem.FileBytes, 0, contentItem.FileBytes.Length);
}
```

Notice anything missing???

I forgot to include:

```
context.Response.Flush();
```

After adding that line of code, it started working in the production environment.  I find it very odd, however, that this was working on the server and not on any clients.  Anyone able to shed any light on why that would be?